# QtOpenGLWidget drawing triangle

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

How can I change the following code so that it actually draws the triangle?

First is the shader, then the implementation of the glwiedget class which is derived from `QOpenglWidget`.

```
// shaders here  
    static const char* vertexShaderSource =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "in vec3 posAttr;\n"
        //"attribute lowp vec3 colAttr;\n"
        //"varying lowp vec4 col;\n"
        //"uniform highp mat4 matrix;\n"
        "void main() {\n"
        //"   col = colAttr;\n"
        "   gl_Position = vec4(posAttr, 1) ;\n"
        "}\n";
// fragment shader
    static const char* fragmentShaderSource =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        //"varying lowp vec4 col;\n"
        "void main() {\n"
        "gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);\n"
        "}\n";


Glwidget::Glwidget(QWidget* parent):QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{

//
}

Glwidget::~Glwidget()
{
    cleanup();
}

void Glwidget::initializeGL()
{
    connect(context(), &QOpenGLContext::aboutToBeDestroyed, this, &Glwidget::cleanup);

    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    glClearColor(.0f, .0f, .0f, 1.0f);
    shader = new QOpenGLShaderProgram(this);

    shader->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, vertexShaderSource);
    shader->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, fragmentShaderSource);
//    posAttribute = shader->attributeLocation("posAttr");
    //colAttribute = shader->attributeLocation("colAttr");
    //matrixAttribute = shader->uniformLocation("matrix");


    Q_ASSERT(shader->link());
    Q_ASSERT(shader->bind());
    //shader->release();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
}
void Glwidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    makeCurrent();
    matrix.perspective(60.0, 4.0f/3.0f, 0.1f, 10.0f);
    matrix.translate(0, 0, -2);
    matrix.rotate(100.0f, 0, 1, 0);
    //shader->setUniformValue(matrixAttribute, matrix);

//    shader->bind();
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        0.0f, 0.707f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f
    };
    shader->setAttributeArray(posAttribute,vertices, 3);

    GLfloat colors[] = {
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };

     glVertexAttribPointer(posAttribute, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
     //glVertexAttribPointer(colAttribute, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, colors);

     glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttribute);
     //glEnableVertexAttribArray(colAttribute);

     glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 1);

     glDisableVertexAttribArray(posAttribute);
     //glDisableVertexAttribArray(colAttribute);
     //shader->release();
}

void Glwidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    matrix.setToIdentity();
    matrix.perspective(45.0f, w / float(h), 0.01f, 1000.0f);
    //glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void Glwidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);
}

void Glwidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);
}

void Glwidget::cleanup()
{
    if (shader == nullptr)
        return;
    makeCurrent();

    delete shader;
    shader = 0;
    doneCurrent();
}
```

Comment: that shader shouldn't even compile, `gl_FragColor` is not part of `#version 330 core`

Comment: @derhass Yes, but only if the context is a core profile context, too (with forward compatibility bit set)

Comment: @Rabbid76: the spec disagrees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to determine the attribute index of `posAttr`, after the program is linked:

```
Q_ASSERT(shader->link());
posAttribute = shader->attributeLocation("posAttr");
```

Since the depth test is enabled, you have to clear the depth buffer. See [`glClear`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClear.xhtml):

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

You do not use any model, view or projection matrix, so the coordinates have to be set in normalized device space. This means all the coordinates have to be in the range [-1.0, 1.0], especially the near plane and far plane of -1.0 and 1.0 have to be considered. By default the depth test function is [`GL_LESS`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDepthFunc.xhtml), so you tringle is clipped by the far plane, because a z coordinate of 1.0 is **not** less than the far plane of 1.0. Use a z coordinate of 0.0, for the vertices (of course somthing like 0.99 would work, too):

```
GLfloat vertices[] = { 0.0f, 0.707f, 0.0f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f };
shader->setAttributeArray(posAttribute,vertices, 3);
```

The 3d paramter of [`glDrawArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml) has to be the number of vertices and not the number of primitives:

```
 glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

The relevant code parts may look like this:

```
void Glwidget::initializeGL()
{
    connect(context(), &QOpenGLContext::aboutToBeDestroyed, this, &Glwidget::cleanup);

    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    glClearColor(.0f, .0f, .0f, 1.0f);
    shader = new QOpenGLShaderProgram(this);

    shader->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, vertexShaderSource);
    shader->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, fragmentShaderSource);

    Q_ASSERT(shader->link());
    posAttribute = shader->attributeLocation("posAttr");

    Q_ASSERT(shader->bind());

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
}

void Glwidget::paintGL()
{
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

     GLfloat vertices[] = { 0.0f, 0.707f, 0.0f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f };
     shader->setAttributeArray(posAttribute,vertices, 3);

     glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttribute);
     glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
     glDisableVertexAttribArray(posAttribute);
}
```

Note, since [Face Culling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling) is enabled, you have to respect the winding order of the primitives (this is the case, in your code).

---

Furthermore, as mentioned by @derhass, in the comments, you have to change the fragment shader. You have to define an [Output Variable](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Outputs).
(Side note, use [Raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)):

```
static const char* fragmentShaderSource = R"(
    #version 330 core

    out vec4 fragColor;

    void main() {
        fragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    }
)";
```

---

See the preview:

[image: polygon]

---

If you want to draw lines instead of polygons, then you can do this by `GL_LINE_LOOP`. See [Line primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Line_primitives).

```
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 3);
```

[image: lines]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the corrections. I still can not see anything. I  and changed the near/far plane to 0 and 1 and the z coordinates of the vertices's to 0.5. still no luck.

Comment: @RingZero What do you mean by *"I and changed the near/far plane to 0 and 1"*? You don't use any matrix at all in the shader code. Of course I tested the code and it works fine for me.

Comment: I am so confused. glxinfo tells me that glsl version 330 core is supported. The shader compiler does not work with core 330. I had to reduce the shader version to 130 to get the program to work. Many thanks. I am very happy now that I have a  working program. :)

Comment: A follow up question. Why the following code does not draw the line ?    GLfloat lvertices[] = { 0.707f, 0.707f, 0.5f, -0.757f, -0.757f, 0.5f };
     GLfloat lcolors[] =   { 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f,    1.0f , 0.0f};
     shader->setAttributeArray(posAttribute, lvertices, 3, 0);
     shader->setAttributeArray(colAttribute, lcolors, 3, 0);
     //glLineWidth(.03f);
     glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 6);
     glDisableVertexAttribArray(posAttribute);
     glDisableVertexAttribArray(colAttribute);

Comment: @RingZero Use `GL_LINE_STRIP` insted of `GL_LINES`. See [Line primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Line_primitives)

Comment: still nothing. I am really considering using the old opengl. This shader stuff is not as easy as the old Opengl.

Comment: @RingZero But it is by far more flexible and performs better.

Comment: I dont see any thing on the screen. No lines at all.

Comment: @RingZero The vertices consists of 3 coordinates and not of 2 as you specified in `{ 0.707f, 0.707f, 0.5f, -0.757f, -0.757f, 0.5f }` use `{ 0.707f, 0.707f, 0.0f, 0.5f, -0.757f, 0.0f, 0.757f, 0.5f, 0.0f };` instead **or** specifiy a tuple size of 2 by `shader->setAttributeArray(posAttribute, lvertices, 2, 0);`.